# Two landscape tables in columns

Tags: tables, minipage, landscape

I am trying to include two landscape tables on one page, with the first one being in the left column and the other placed in the right one. I have tried several solutions including the minipage solution. I could not 'force' the second one into the right column with minipage, any suggestions?

I have the following code:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
 1&1&1\\
\hline
2&2&2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
1&1&1\\
\hline
2&2&2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

This is the standard twocolumn-setup in landscape mode, I am trying to rotate the tables (landscape)  but displayed horizontally in a minipage setup. I dont know if this is the correct approach, but its the closest I've got.

Comment: Can you show what you've got at this point?

Comment: As egreg suggests, it would be useful, for it is not clear what captions and where you want to place, and for other reasons.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is clearly that you've got too much text on the line:

```
0.5\textwidth + 0.5\textwidth + <space> + 0.5cm
```

is off by more than 0.5cm.

You should try loading the `caption` or `captionof` package and write

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{flushleft}% to avoid indentation

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
 1&1&1\\
\hline
2&2&2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\captionof{table}{First caption}

\end{minipage}% no space between the minipages
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
1&1&1\\
\hline
2&2&2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\captionof{table}{Second caption}

\end{minipage}
\end{landscape}
```